# Problema con repeticion en c

Tags: array, c

estoy haciendo un proyecto para la universidad, y tengo que hacer el juego yahtzee, y tengo un fallo en el codigo que no consigo solucionar, quiero que me repita la segunda sentencia dos veces y no lo consigo

```
for(jugada=0;jugada<1;jugada++)
{
    for(tiro=0;tiro<3;tiro++)
    {
       if(tiro==0)
       {
          lanzar_dados(dados);        
       }
       else
       {
          printf("\nQue dados quieres lanzar %c: ",63);
          fflush(stdin);
          fgets(dados_lanzar,5,stdin);  
          printf("tonto");
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: `for(jugada=0;jugada<1;jugada++)` solo ejecutará el bucle una vez. Si quieres que sean dos, tendrás que poner `for(jugada=0;jugada<2;jugada++)`

Comment: Te resuelve el "problema" poner `"tonto\n"` en vez de `"tonto"`?

Comment: el bucle que quiero que se me repita es el de tiro

Comment: El bucle `for(tiro=0;tiro<3;tiro++)` se repite 3 veces. Cual es realmente tu problema?

Comment: Hola Adrian, puedes explicar mejor el resultado esperado y el resultado obtenido? mira [mcve] para mejorar la pregunta., Un saludo